# problem with updmap in texlive

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I have just installed texlive 2022, specifically mactex.  Whenever I install a new version of texlive, I also have to update font mappings because I use some special (commercial) fonts.  The 2-step procedure for this, which I long ago gleaned from latex help sites is the following. In a terminal run

1. sudo -H mktexlsr
2. sudo -H updmap-sys --force --enable Map=newfont.map,

where newfont stands for the name of my commercial font.  This time around the updmap command failed with the complaint that the options were not recognized.  Specifically, the response the updmap command as given is
Unknown option: force --enable Map

The man file for updmap tells me that the syntax is still good.

I assume that updmap is actually specific to the active tex distribution  texlive 2022, but I switched my default tex distribution back to texlive 2021 and tried this again, and the same thing happened.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having problems getting Minion Pro updmapped properly.

Comment: It turned out my problem was not actually a tex/updmap problem at all.  I was copying my terminal commands from a file, and the file was corrupted so the commands wouldn't parse.  The problem was solved by typing in the commands.